# catch null object in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i catch the object is null or not an object. Actually i have wrote this line in if condition for solving it, but not working.

But Generating ERROR :- "object is null or not an object"

```
var preWynum = "";
function paint(Wynum)
{
    // alert("Wynum:"+Wynum +", preWynum:"+preWynum);
    if(document.getElementById(preWynum) && document.getElementById(Wynum))
    {
      document.getElementById(preWynum).style.backgroundColor='white';
      document.getElementById(Wynum).style.backgroundColor='yellow';
    }

   preWynum = Wynum; 

}
```

I dont believe why it not running.
 Any other idea ?

preWynum and Wynum is the id of tr(table row).

I want to set background color with yellow to current selected row(that's id is Wynum).

Comment: Does the error happen in the `if` clause by any chance?

Comment: `preWynum` seems to be empty... you get `null` if you pass an empty string to `getElementById`.

Comment: @Felix Kling If its null or empty then condition should be false, but is not.

Comment: True... are you sure the error is thrown there? Can you create a jsfiddle.net example that demonstrates your problem? I guess it is somehow related to the code you did not post ;)

Comment: You posted the function definition and the preWynum variable definition, but how about the actual function call where it's erroring?

Comment: OHH ! SORRY ! ACTUALLY THIS FUNCTION IS NOT CALLED, A ANOTHER FUNCTION NAMED Paint2 IS CALLED, THAT IS EDITING SIMULTANEOUSLY BY MY COLLEAGUE, THANKS FOR YOUR SUPPORT... REMEMBERED BY AS Michael TOLD AT CALLING LOCATION OF THE FUNCTION...

Comment: @J.J. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you are passing an object (non-existent) to `getElementById()` when it expects a string:

```
// Put quotes around 'preWynum' and 'Wynum'
if(document.getElementById('preWynum') && document.getElementById('Wynum'))
{
  document.getElementById('preWynum').style.backgroundColor='white';
  document.getElementById('Wynum').style.backgroundColor='yellow';
}
```

Comment: Actually preWynum and Wynum are variables. which have values passed in function ... :)-

Comment: @J.J. If they're variables, please also show us the code that sets them, as it may be faulty.